# Find Unique values across multiple columns in a Dataframe for Each Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
ID  Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4...
1   2019-08-01 2019-08-04 2019-08-02 2019-08-01
2   2019-08-01 NaN        NaN        Nan 
3   2019-08-01 2019-08-04 2019-07-02 2019-06-01
...
```

and i want to count the number of unique dates in columns Date1-Date4 to get:

```
ID Unique_Dates
1  3
2  1
3  4
```

I have ~600K records, so an efficient process would be great!

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How do I ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- (2) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve